# What should be the content of a post submitted form validation message

Tags: forms, validation, copywriting

Say I have a form, I submitted it, and received an error.

While each field with error is marked in a red frame and has an icon, and mouseover shows the exact reason for this error.

should the bottom (above the save / cancel) error be:

- General, for EX: **you have 2 errors, please review the fields marked with X above.**
- Or, specific, EX: **Shift time exceed group available hours.**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to the trouble to have a mouseover with more specific information, I'd make the information above the save/cancel generic like you have done: letting them know there are errors and how many. The mouseover of the error has specific information about how to fix the error and it's in the right spot - where the error has occurred, so the user doesn't have to look for it. I don't think repeating the specific error information above the save/cancel would be helpful to the user - it could create confusion if it was specific: for instance, if the user has never used this screen before, they might not know that the specific error information is repeated next to the actual error - so they might think they have to remember the specific information while they look for their errors to correct.

Comment: I would concur with this, especially given you've got a "generic" "_1 Error, review the fields mark[ed] with X above_" in the bottom-right corner (which I think is a good place to put it, since it's next to the Save/Cancel buttons).

Comment: sorry @stolbot I didn't understand your answer, can you please explain why you think I should created a specific message? what will I do when I have 3 errors for example? what about localization? some templates don't have a lot of available space..

Comment: @EranBar Possibly you and Stolbot are talking about two different things. I believe Eran was thinking you were asking about the message that appears on mouseover, which he believes should be specific (I also thought you were asking about that message, and agree it should be specific). Given your response, perhaps you were asking about the message in the bottom-right next to the Cancel/Save buttons. If so, then that should (I think) probably be general, more or less as you have it. If I'm wrong in what I've said, please can you clarify in your question which message you are asking about.